# Mask cells where column name equals index (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to mask out the values in a Pandas DataFrame where the index is the same as the column name. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape((4, 3)),
                 index=["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                 columns=["a", "b", "c"])

   a   b   c
a  0   1   2
b  3   4   5
c  6   7   8
d  9  10  11
```

After masking:

```
   a   b   c
a NaN  1   2
b  3  NaN  5
c  6   7  NaN
d  9  10  11
```

Seems simple enough but I'm not sure how to do it in a Pythonic way, without iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use broadcasting as well:

```
a.mask(a.index[:,None] == a.columns[None,:])
```

Or

```
a.mask(a.index.values[:,None] == a.columns.values[None,:])
```

Output:

```
     a     b     c
a  NaN   1.0   2.0
b  3.0   NaN   5.0
c  6.0   7.0   NaN
d  9.0  10.0  11.0
```

Comment: Nice!  I like this approach! +1

Answer (score 5):

Try using [pd.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) to apply a condtion to each dataframe column that matches the index with the series/column name.  The result of the apply is a boolean dataFrame and use [pd.Dataframe.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
a.mask(a.apply(lambda x: x.name == x.index))
```

Output:

```
     a     b     c
a  NaN   1.0   2.0
b  3.0   NaN   5.0
c  6.0   7.0   NaN
d  9.0  10.0  11.0
```

---

Also, [inspired by @QuangHoang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61876607/6361531) you can use np.equal.outer:

```
a.mask(np.equal.outer(a.index, a.columns))
```

Output:

```
     a     b     c
a  NaN   1.0   2.0
b  3.0   NaN   5.0
c  6.0   7.0   NaN
d  9.0  10.0  11.0
```

Comment: Upvote ,  I like your approach with the outer function,
with Quang Hoangs I get a:
FutureWarning: Support for multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.  Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.
  a.mask(a.index[:,np.newaxis]==a.columns[np.newaxis,:],1)

Answer (score 2):

Using `DataFrame.stack` and `index.get_level_values`:

```
st = a.stack()
m = st.index.get_level_values(0) == st.index.get_level_values(1) 
a = st.mask(m).unstack()

     a     b     c
a  NaN   1.0   2.0
b  3.0   NaN   5.0
c  6.0   7.0   NaN
d  9.0  10.0  11.0
```